# USB getting data from a device

Tags: c, usb, libusb

I am trying to read data from a [HID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_interface_device) device. I have a USB sniffer capture that basically does:

```
Get Device Descriptor
Get Device Descriptor
Set Address
Get Configuration Descriptor
Get Configuration Descriptor
Set Configuration
Set Idle
Get Input Report
Get Input Report
Get Input Report
Get Input Report
Set Feature Report
Get Input Report
Set Feature Report
Get Input Report
Get Input Report
Set Output Report
Get Input Report
Set Feature Report
Input Report
Input Report
```

It appears that everything before the `Input Report` is setup and that `Input Report` is the regular data collection from the device.

In [libusb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libusb), I am doing the following:

```
usb_init();
usb_find_busses();
usb_find_devices();

loop through busses
    loop through devices
        if correct vendor and correct product
            handle = usb_open(device)
            break

usb_set_configuration(dev_handle, 1)

// Endpoint 0 is a 'write endpoint', endpoint 1 is a 'read endpoint'.
endpoint = &device->config[0].interface[0].altsetting[0].endpoint[1]
usb_claim_interface(dev_handle, 0)
usb_set_altinterface(dev_handle, 0)

usb_bulk_read(dev_handle, endpoint->bEndpointAddress, buffer, endpoint->wMaxPacketSize, 1);
```

I am guessing that the driver and the code up to `usb_set_configuration` corresponds with the sniffer analysis up to `Set Configuration`.

Everything in the code succeeds until the `usb_bulk_read` which fails.

1. How do I `Set Idle`, `Get Input Report`, `Set Feature Report`, `Set Output Report`?
2. Why does the `usb_bulk_read` fail?
3. What else do I need to do to set up communication with my device?

Comment: Which usb-sniffer did you use to get the above report?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm new to libusb and [USB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB) in general, so I'm not sure if this is the right thing, but after looking at the output from a USB sniffer such as [USBlyzer](http://www.usblyzer.com/) and tweaking several things I come up with the following protocol items:

### usb_claim_interface

When I claimed an interface (`usb_claim_interface`) and then cancelled my application, I was in an inoperable state on subsequent runs. I tried various resets (`usb_reset` and `usb_resetep`), but I still could not get proper usage out of `usb_control_msg`.

### SetReport / GetReport

`USBlyzer` showed that the relevant packets where `Get Descriptor`, `Select Configuration`, `Set Report`, and `Get Report`. `Get Descriptor` and `Select Configuration` are clearly associated with `usb_get_descriptor` and `usb_set_configuration` respectively.

Some `Get Report` packets contained `Feature Id` and others `Input Id`. I was able to match these with `usb_control_msg` with the following parameters, ([libusb.c](http://www.koders.com/c/fidC70055E10CB95735FD3D7A78CF990AA3929C991C.aspx?s=%22Marek%20Kralewski%22) helped
me figure this out):

```
requesttype = USB_ENDPOINT_IN | USB_TYPE_CLASS | USB_RECIP_INTERFACE
value = 0x01 (for GetReport)
index = id | (0x03 << 8) (for FeatureId)
```

`Set Report` packets also used `Feature Id` but `Output Id`. From looking at the details it became clear that `Input Id` matches (0x01 << 8) and `Output Id` matches (0x02 << 8). So to get `Set Report` I called `usb_control_msg` with these adjusted params:

```
requesttype = USB_ENDPOINT_OUT | USB_TYPE_CLASS | USB_RECIP_INTERFACE
value = 0x09 (for SetReport)
index = id | (0x03 << 8) (for FeatureId)
```

This may not be the "right" way to do all this, and I would certainly appreciate any deeper insight into what is happening with the various functions of the [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface). But this was able to get my host to capture all relevant data from the device.

Answer (score 3):

> HID device [...]
>   usb_bulk_read

Ouch. USB Bulk read is only used on Bulk endpoints, and HID has none.

HID endpoints are interrupt endpoints, and thus need `usb_interrupt_transfer()`. You *did* look at the endpoint descriptor, didn't you? It should declare the endpoint type as interrupt.

Comment: some hid devices has control endpoints as well (Endpoint IN and Endpoint OUT) for set_Outputreport and get_InputReport as well.Basically for configuration section - setting feature reports.